ValueError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input. CNN-XGBOOST
import numpy as np
import pickle
import keras
from scipy import stats
import xgboost as xgb
from datetime import datetime
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras import regularizers
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from keras.models import model_from_json

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import tensorflow as tf

def load_cnn_model(X_test, y_test):
    # load json and create model
    json_file = open('/home/steve/Desktop/deep-xgboost-image-classifier-main/code/baseline/model.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    # load weights into new model
    loaded_model.load_weights("/home/steve/Desktop/deep-xgboost-image-classifier-main/code/baseline/model.weights.h5")
     
    # evaluate loaded model on test data
    opt_rms = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001, decay=1e-6)
    loaded_model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=opt_rms,
        metrics=['accuracy'])

    y_test_ = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

    scores = loaded_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test_, batch_size=128, verbose=1)
    print('\nTest result: %.3f loss: %.3f\n' % (scores[1]*100,scores[0]))

    return loaded_model

def get_feature_layer(model, data):
    model.predict(data[:1])

    total_layers = len(model.layers)
    
    fl_index = total_layers-2
    
    feature_layer_model = keras.Model(
        inputs=model.input,
        outputs=model.get_layer(index=fl_index).output)


    feature_layer_output = feature_layer_model.predict(data)
    
    return feature_layer_output

def xgb_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):

    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(
        X_train,
        label=y_train
    )

    dtest = xgb.DMatrix(
        X_test,
        label=y_test
    )

    results = {}

    params = {
        'max_depth':12,
        'eta':0.05,
        'objective':'multi:softprob',
        'num_class':10,
        'early_stopping_rounds':10,
        'eval_metric':'merror'
    }

    watchlist = [(dtrain, 'train'),(dtest, 'eval')]
    n_round = 400

    model = xgb.train(
        params,
        dtrain,
        n_round,
        watchlist,
        evals_result=results)

    pickle.dump(model, open("cnn_xgboost_final.pickle.dat", "wb"))

    return model

def main():

    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

    mean = np.mean(X_train,axis=(0,1,2,3))
    std = np.std(X_train,axis=(0,1,2,3))
    X_train = (X_train-mean)/(std+1e-7)
    X_test = (X_test-mean)/(std+1e-7)

    cnn_model = load_cnn_model(X_test, y_test)
    print("Loaded CNN model from disk")

    X_train_cnn =  get_feature_layer(cnn_model,X_train)
    print("Features extracted of training data")
    X_test_cnn = get_feature_layer(cnn_model,X_test)
    print("Features extracted of test data\n")

    print("Build and save of CNN-XGBoost Model.")
    model = xgb_model(X_train_cnn, y_train, X_test_cnn, y_test)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

This is my code.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steve/Desktop/deep-xgboost-image-classifier-main/code/baseline/cnn_xgboost.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/steve/Desktop/deep-xgboost-image-classifier-main/code/baseline/cnn_xgboost.py", line 119, in main
    X_train_cnn =  get_feature_layer(cnn_model,X_train)
  File "/home/steve/Desktop/deep-xgboost-image-classifier-main/code/baseline/cnn_xgboost.py", line 58, in get_feature_layer
    inputs=model.input,
  File "/usr/local/Public_Anaconda3/anaconda3/envs/Steve-DXIC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 228, in input
    return self._get_node_attribute_at_index(0, "input_tensors", "input")
  File "/usr/local/Public_Anaconda3/anaconda3/envs/Steve-DXIC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 259, in _get_node_attribute_at_index
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input.

The above is my error. Before running this, I ran another project to create model.json and model.weights.h5,but why I met this problem?
The above is my problem. Before running this, I ran another project to create model.json and model.weights.h5,but why I met this problem?
https://github.com/jonaac/deep-xgboost-image-classifier This is the website.
